# WPML Category translation

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I have a plugin that create two categories Properties and Propietes (French), the problem is that I have WPML installed and both categories are created on the same language (French). I can manually move Properties to the english and relate them, but I'd like to do it from the plugin.

I google a little bit and find out that the table which has the translations is (wp prefix)icl_translations, and tried to add the necessary information in order to make the link between both categories without luck.

Do you have any suggestion o somewhere where I should look at in order to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you want to do it manually in the admin? Far safer and simpler. If you really need to do it in code, you could use wpml's own functions - `global $sitepress;`, then `$sitepress->set_element_language_details()` ( or something similar, look it up in the plugin's code ) with the relevant arguments for each term. You would also need `$sitepress->get_element_trid()` after the first one has been made translateable.

Comment: I don't want to do it manually because it will be part of the core function of my plugin.
Thanks a lot, I'll take a look and let you know how it go.